# How can I create a complex array?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple question for you:

```
#include < iostream> 
#include < complex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int k=200000;

    complex <double> r0[k/2],r1[k/2]; ///wrong!!!

    complex <float> r0[k/2],r1[k/2];  ///right

    return 0;
}
```

I just wanna create a complex array. `k=200000` here, the computer stop working (not error, it shows my file stop working),  if i just `complex <double>`, it works with `complex<float>`! What could be the reason?

Comment: You should accept some answers to your questions. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You are "blowing up the stack" - when you have local variable in main, like this, it will use space on the stack. In this case, `k * sizeof double` or `k * sizeof float` - since typical compilers use 4 bytes for float, we're talking about 800KB for the second variant, and 1.6MB for the first variant if the stack is only 1MB, then the first one will go way beyond the size of the stack.

There are several solutions, one of which is of course to adopt the proper C++ method of using vector:

```
vector<complex <double> > r0, r1;

r0.resize(k/2);
r1.resize(k/2);
```

Two other options

Allocate dynamically:

```
complex<double> *r0 = new complex<double>[k/2];

...

delete [] r0;
```

Or make r0 and r1 global variables.